# When I want to randomly assign a role by doing random.shuffle i get this error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Tags: python

I have recently begun working on a small program and I wanted to use the random.shuffle way of giving someone a random role. Everything works great up until I reach the part where the role is actually mentioned.

```
import random
roles = ['Lizard','Human']

random.shuffle(roles)

name = input("Enter Your Name")

color = input("Select a color \n Blue \n Red \n Green \n Yellow \n Color: ")

print(name + " You are " + random.shuffle(roles))
```

Comment: `random.shuffle(roles)` returns None. Perhaps in the last line you meant to use `random.choice(roles)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't expect to get a returned value from a processed object. This line will give you an error because you expect a returned value from None input `print(name + " You are " + random.shuffle(roles))`.

So, you need to understand how `random.shuffle` works. `random.shuffle` is a function that takes a list and *swap* its values, randomly. So, what you need to do is only one thing which declares the role after you executed--> *called* the `random.shuffle` function.

*So, It has to go like that*:-

```py
import random
roles = ['Lizard','Human']

random.shuffle(roles) # called function to swap the values of the roles _list

name = input("Enter Your Name")

color = input("Select a color \n Blue \n Red \n Green \n Yellow \n Color: ").upper() # upper() function for giving the user to write whatever he want in case you want to use this input for any other later benefits...

print(name + " You are " + roles[0]) # declaring the first value in the list doesn't mean it will be 'lizard' after randomly swapping it may display as 'human' or 'lizard'
```

*Examples of* ***OUTPUT***

```
# Output No. 1: -

Enter Your Name Jhon
Select a color 
 Blue 
 Red 
 Green 
 Yellow 
 Color: Blue
 Jhon You are Human

# Output No. 2

Enter Your Name Slave
Select a color 
 Blue 
 Red 
 Green 
 Yellow 
 Color: green
 Slave You are Lizard
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) shuffles the list *in-place*, but the function's return value is not the shuffled list, but actually `None`.

As an alternative, the function [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) randomly chooses an element from its argument. I think this is what you'd like to use. Your code should then look like:

```
import random

roles = ['Lizard', 'Human']

name = input("Enter Your Name")
color = input("Select a color \n Blue \n Red \n Green \n Yellow \n Color: ")

print(name + ", you are a " + random.choice(roles))
```

Note that there is no need to shuffle the `roles` list beforehand.